# How to assign a domain to my website hosted in Azure LInux VM?

Tags: linux, azure, dns

In my azure account i have created a Linux VM on which i have hosted my files instead of creating a webapp resource.

I have installed all the required software & uploaded my files via FTP. Now i can access my site by using the ip say **http://11.22.32.44**

I have also purchase a domain from register.com. Suppose my domain name is example.com

I want to access my website with my domain name now. Like **example.com** instead of **http://11.22.32.44**

I am new to this type of things plus i don't have much knowledge in Azure.

Please Help.

Comment: May i know the down vote reason please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to access my website with my domain name now. Like example.com
>   instead of http://11.22.32.44

According to your description, we can add a **A record** to register.com.
We should do this in the domain name manager web page, map the domian name to this public IP address, in this way, we can access this web via example.com.

Same as this image:[image]

More information about add A record, please refer to this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-at-Register-com-for-Office-365-55bd8c38-3316-48ae-a368-4959b2c1684e).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain me what is * & @ here?

Comment: '@' is DNS shorthand for a record at the root or 'apex' of a DNS zone. For example, if your DNS zone is 'contoso.com', and you want a DNS record that is also 'contoso.com', then you use '@' as the record name.