# Subdomain not working after changing the nameservers

Tags: azure, dns, nameservers, azure-virtual-network

I have hosted my website in **Microsoft Azure**. I have purchased the domain from **register.com**.

I have used a Linux VM for my project deployment.

Suppose my website name is **example.com**. I have created a sub domain for it called **app.example.com**

It was working fine but its not working when i created a DNS Zone resource in my azure account & updated those nameserver name in my register.com site.

Comment: Did you make an entry in Azure DNS Zone to point the subdomain to your app URL. 

You could make an entry as *.example.com --> myappservice.azurewebsite.net to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, we can follow those steps to setup Azure DNS zone and your domain name:
1. Add **record set** via azure portal, point to your Azure VM:
[image]

2.Add **NS record** to register.com, like this:

```
Host: web.jasonye.com  
Record type:     NS record  
Value:    ns1-01.azure-dns.com
```

After a few mins, we can use **nslookup** to **verify** name resoution is working or not:

```
nslookup -type=SOA jasonye.com
```

The following is an example response from the preceding command:

```
C:\Users>nslookup -type=SOA jasonye.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2404:f801:10:12e:fe::2

Non-authoritative answer:
jasonye.com
        primary name server = ns1-01.azure-dns.com
        responsible mail addr = azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry   = 300 (5 mins)
        expire  = 2419200 (28 days)
        default TTL = 300 (5 mins)

ns1-01.azure-dns.com    internet address = 40.90.4.1
```

After that, we can access this web via IE:
[image]

More information about Azure DNS zone, please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns).

> Each registrar has their own DNS management tools to change the name
>   server records for a domain. In the registrar's DNS management page,
>   edit the NS records and replace the NS records with the ones Azure DNS
>   created.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: My client asked to me not to use azure nameserver rather use nameserver where he has purchased the domain. How can we achieve that?

Comment: @pkk if you want to use other domain name from third party, we can use `A record` , please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580711/how-to-assign-a-domain-to-my-website-hosted-in-azure-linux-vm/43580857#43580857