# How to setup Azure CNAME

Tags: azure, ubuntu, dns, vps, cname

I am setting up a VPS on Azure and am stuck at configing the CNAME. The site is registered with a 3rd party.

I have setup the following:

```
NAME TYPE  TTL   VALUE
@    NS    120   ns1-01.azure-dns.com ... etc
@    SOA   3600  azuredns...
www  CNAME 3600
```

I am stuck at what to put for the CNAME value. At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name it mentions using

```
myapp.azurewebsites.net
```

however for another VPS on azure I am using

```
otherapp.location.cloudapp.azure.com
```

In the azure docs they show how to find ip details for a hosted webapp https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name but no mention on how to find for a hosted VPS.

Any idea where can I find the details for what I should use?

Comment: Do you want to map your domain name to this VM with CNAME?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Yes please. The issues I have are: I cant find my public IP address on the azure portal. I also cant find details on what full address I should use for the www CNAME alias for my DNS zone in azure, and cant find the latest info on what domain name servers I should use for my domain registrar to point to Azure

Comment: Can't find the FQDN or public IP address of this Azure VM?

Comment: do you mean you want to map your domain name to azure DNS zone?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT yes to both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to map your domain name for this Azure VM, we can add CNAME to the third party follow those steps:
1.Add **FQDN** to this VM first(configure this with Azure public IP):
[image]

2.**login** your 3rd party domain register configure page, then **add** CNAME like this:

```
Host          type                value
xxxxx         CNAME              jasontest321.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

More information about add FQDN to this VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/portal-create-fqdn).

If you add record to **DNS zone**, and you want to map your 3rd party domain name map to Azure DNS zone, we can follow those steps in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603048/subdomain-not-working-after-changing-the-nameservers/43605334#43605334).