# How to map a custom domain name with an Azure server?

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns, virtual-machine

I know this question has been asked numerous times here but I still don't get the solution, sorry about that.

I deployed a wordpress multi site VM on my Azure account and purchased a domain name "https://jobinwrites.com" from Azure DNS service. I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) to map an "A record" to the IP address of this Azure VM:

[image: A record]
[image: CNAME record]

And this is how the overview of the Azure VM looks like:

[image: Azure VM overview]

When I hit the IP address of the machine or the jobinwrites.westus.cloudapp.azure.com domain, I correctly hit the service. However, when I try jobinwrites.com, the browser returns a DNS address not found exception. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick note: The link you provided to was for setting up a custom domain on a Web App, however, it seems you are trying to set it up on a VM.

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET: Yes, that's correct. I was hoping they would be pretty similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to map a custom domain name to your Azure VM, we should buy this custom domain name first.

**Azure DNS is not the domain registrar.**

We should login your 3rd party domain register configure page.
Each registrar has their own DNS management tools to change the name server records for a domain. In the registrar's DNS management page, add a new A record, like this:

```
Host          type                value
xxxxx         A                  104.42.230.37
```

If you want to add a CNAME record, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083082/how-to-setup-azure-cname/44083612#44083612).

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.