# Can an Azure NIC be pointed to records one created in an Azure DNS zone?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Is there a way to point an Azure NIC to the records one created in an Azure DNS zone?

[image]

Comment: @garbrad . Could you confirm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present Azure DNS doesn't support private DNS zones, i.e. those only available to your vnet.  Also, the DNS servers specified in the "Add DNS server" box needs to be a recursive resolver, Azure DNS is an Authoritative DNS service, i.e. it will only serve answers for the zones it hosts.

Comment: @jason-ye-msft  Are private DNS zones being considered for a future release?

Comment: How do I do this now?

Answer (score 1):

We **can't** add Azure DNS zone to NIC custom DNS. The custom DNS required **IP address**, we can add the DNS server IP address to it.
 For example, we can add `8.8.8.8` to it, also we can add local DNS server IP address to it(need VPN). Or create a Azure windows VM and install DNS role on it, and add this VM ip address to it.

If you want to use Azure DNS zone to manage your records, we can map your own domain name to DNS zone, and add name servers to your domain name(add this by domain name registrar manage webpage).

The following image shows an example DNS query about Azure DNS zone:
[image]

If you want to add record to DNS zone, and you want to map your 3rd party domain name map to Azure DNS zone, we can follow those steps in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603048/subdomain-not-working-after-changing-the-nameservers/43605334#43605334).

**Note**:

Keep in mind Azure DNS is **not** the domain registrar, we should buy domain name from domain registrar(like godaddy, register.com).

---

**Update**:
If you just want to use domain name in your virtual network, there is no need to buy a domain, we can use AAD DS in our virtual network. Or we can deploy a VM and install DC on it, work as on-prem.

By the way, in the same virtual network, we can ping VM's name by default.

Comment: @garbrad Is there a Channel 9 video on how to map one's domain to the DNS zone and add name servers to the domain name; the shortest way to point a NIC to the DNS zone.....Sry, I'm a Hyper-V guy...

Comment: @AyanMullick which domain register your domain name buy from?

Comment: It's registered with Neustar

Comment: @AyanMullick we can login Neustar manage page, and add NS record to it.

Comment: Its the state's workload. The approval chain for something like that is a nightmare. I was hoping there would be a shorter way to point a vNic to the zone records in Azure. But garbrad confirmed private zones aren't supported....

Comment: @AyanMullick another way, we can associate a public IP address to this VM, and add FQDN to this Public IP address, then map your own domain name to this FQDN, in this way, we can browse your own domain name to this vm.

Comment: I was trying for a cloud only Infrastructure setup where I could replace the DC with 'Azure domain services' and the DNS with 'Azure DNS zones'.

Comment: @AyanMullick Do you want that domain name can be access via the Internet? if not we can use AAD DS to replace DC. If you want it can be access via the internet, we should buy a domain name. Please let me know if you would like further assistance. Also if it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)

Comment: No. I don't need the domain name to be accessed over the internet.

Comment: @AyanMullick I see, you are right, if no need the domain name to be accessed over the internet, we just add VMs in the AAD DS's vnet, then we can use the domain name to communicate with other VMs in the Vnet. No need to buy domain name:) hope this helpful