# How to set up Azure DNS zone for www.domainname.com without affect mail.domainname.com

Tags: azure, email, web, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a domainname and webapp currently which I need to do a set up for the domain to point to my webapp server.
I only need to point to www.domainname.com to my Azure DNS zone and mail.domainname.com point to another email provider. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only need to point to www.domainname.com to my Azure DNS zone and
>   mail.domainname.com point to another email provider. How can I do
>   this?

Azure DNS zone works like the domain name manager, we can delegate your domain name to Azure DNS zone, then we can add `A record` to map www.domainname.com to your application.

About point mail.domainname.com tp another email provider, we can add `mx record` in your domain name management page.

Here [A similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603048/subdomain-not-working-after-changing-the-nameservers/43605334#43605334) about Azure DNS zone and custom domain name, please refer to it.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.